# Loading PDF on webPage for the ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, pdf, offline

I'm developing a mostly offline piece of software and iv been looking into loading up a PDF file that ideally should be stored locally on the iPad. For what it's worth I am developing in phone gap and doing the majority of my coding in JavaScript. Any information/links really anything on this subject would be a big help. I'm kinda at a loss on this one

Thanks a ton
-postSYnaptic

Comment: Are you trying to load the file in-app or have it opened by a separate app on the device such as safari?

Comment: From the app itself my application is supposed to be as offline as possible so I'm searching desperately for a way to store the PDF locally and pull it up from the app itself

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as this should trigger the default pdf viewer:

```
<embed id="pdf" name="pdf" src="URL_TO_PDF" width="100" height="100" />
```

regards

Comment: My thinking is that it's not that simple. Im pretty sure that you can't reference data on the iPad by directory locations. But then again I have no idea how you store that data to begin with somaybe I'm wrong. That's what my question is really